# ошибка DataTypeConverter в Java 9

Tags: java, sql-server

вылезает ошибка при попытке получить SQL Server данные. Прочитал, что в Java 9 убрали DataTypeConverter. Помогите решить проблему

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
```

а вот сам код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        String userName = "sa";
        String password = "34erdfcV";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://адрессервера"+";databaseName=имяБД";
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        Statement s1 = ((java.sql.Connection) con).createStatement();


        ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery("SELECT TOP (1000) [idBuildings]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[lat1]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[lon1]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[id2gis]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[lat2]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[lon2]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[route1]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[DistanceP]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[DistanceM]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[TimeP]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[TimeM]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[PolygonP]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[PolygonM]\r\n" + 
                "      ,[Radius]\r\n" + 
                "  FROM [ast_2gis].[dbo].[rn_allRoutesNew]");

        String[] result = new String[20];
        if(rs!=null){
            while (rs.next()){
                for(int i = 0; i <result.length ;i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j <result.length;j++)
                    {
                        result[j]=rs.getString(i);
                    System.out.println(result[j]);
                }
                }
            }
        }



    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Его не убрали, а вынесли JAXB из стандартной библиотеки в модуль. Либо оформите свою программу в модуль и явно импортируйте JAXB, либо положите JAXB в classpath.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы собираете и запускаете вашу программу только в Java 9, то самый простой способ:

```
javac --add-modules java.xml.bind SomeClass.java
java --add-modules java.xml.bind SomeClass
```

Либо можно скачать [jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar), положить куда-нибудь и указать в classpath:

```
javac -cp jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar SomeClass.java
java -cp .;jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar SomeClass
```

В данном примере исходник, класс и jar-файл находятся в одном каталоге.

Если используете maven, просто укажите в pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```