# Java 9 Dependency

Tags: java, maven

Проект работал на JDK 1.8.0_161.
Обновил JDK до 9.0.4. 
В итоге слетели зависимоcти всех библиотек, подключаемые через pom.xml.
И заново они не подгружаются. Пробовал удалять, добавлять заново - ничего.
Работаю в IDEA.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Из 9 жавы выпилили классы, которые использовались в библиотеках, подключаемых вами.

Comment: Спасибо, подозревал это.

Comment: @aleshka-batman откуда вы знаете какие классы автор подключает? И что-то я не помню, чтобы из Java 9 что-либо "выпилиливали"?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev А в чем тогда проблема? Вернулся на java 8, все заработало....почти все)

Comment: @Danilka37 увидеть бы ошибки, было бы понятнее в чём проблема. Чаще всего народ напарывается на вынос JAXB в отдельный модуль.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev ДА! Именно JAXB вылетает. Пишет нет такого класса. Решил проблему откатом до JDK 1.8.0_161. Т.к. обновление подключаемых бибилотек до последних версий эффекта не дало.

Comment: @Danilka37 тогда [я уже отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743116/204271) на такой вопрос.