# Ошибка в HibernateUtil.java

Tags: java, hibernate, java-9

Ошибка `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` .

Класс `HibernateUtil` :

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

`HibernateUtil.cfg.xml` :

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/personal</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <mapping class="Entity.UsersEntity"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. postgres установлен, связь установлена.

Добавил зависимости :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Ошибка :

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at DAO.UserDAO.list(UserDAO.java:43)
    at Controllers.ControllerRegistration.dublicateEmail(ControllerRegistration.java:259)
    at Controllers.ControllerRegistration.lambda$emailTF$4(ControllerRegistration.java:172)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:8134)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$12.invalidated(Scene.java:2183)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setFocusOwner(Scene.java:4043)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.requestFocus(Scene.java:4090)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1700(Scene.java:4029)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.requestFocus(Scene.java:2150)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.requestFocus(Node.java:8295)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.mousePressed(TextFieldBehavior.java:253)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at Util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Добавьте в код полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Похоже, вы используете 9 или 10-ю версию Java. Так?

Comment: Все верно, 9 версия

Comment: Hibernate использует JAXB, а его в Java 9 [вынесли из стандартной библиотеки в модуль java.xml.bind](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742700/204271).

Comment: Ошибка осталась та же. + еще 5 нових ошибок WARNING

Comment: Ошибка `NoSuchMethodError` обычно означает несовместимость версий библиотек.

Comment: ошибка `ExceptionInInitializerError`  как ее решить ?

Comment: @FediaCholak Пофиксить ошибку которая является главной причиной этой ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы внимательно прочитаете всю трассировку, то сможете заметить, что причиной исключения `ExceptionInInitializerError` послужило исключение `NoSuchMethodError`. Исключение `NoSuchMethodError` служит признаком несовместимости версий библиотек. Судя по `javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;` несовместимость в версия JPA.

Comment: Удалил некоторье зависимости jaxb, и ошибка изменилась. Теперь ConfigurationException. Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: А теперь вашей программе снова не хватает JAXB. Я не бесконечно заниматься с вами подбором правильного сочетания зависимостей. Вы должны понимать, что вы используете, как, и какие между ними взаимосвязи.

Comment: Так помогите, как решить ету проблему ?

Comment: Сергей, так вы мне поможете ? А то вроде в ответе написали что знаете, но решения не написали.

Comment: Нет волшебного рецепта помогающего во всех случаях. Надо анализировать взаимосвязи используемых в вашем проекте зависимостей и подбирать необходимое сочетание библиотек совместимых версий. Я не готов этим заниматься. К тому же такая помощь уже выходит за пределы формата Stackoverflow.

Comment: То есть ваш ответ, что нужно хаотично подбирать зависимости ? Я же скинул те зависимости которье я использую, их не так много чтобь запутатся опьтному програмисту. И почиму виходит за предель сайта, по моему сайт для того и создан чтобь делится опьтом и знаниями.

Comment: Нет, мой ответ в том, что надо понимать как работает каждая библиотека, от чего зависит и почему. И пользуясь этими знаниями проанализировать ситуацию характерную только для вашего проекта.

Comment: У меня еще мало опыта, и потому не все понимаю. Но раз вы хорошо знаете библиотеки тогда скажите мне ответ.

Comment: Вы дали ответ будто все очень легко, просто я ничего не понимаю. Но решения дать не можете.

Comment: Повторяю, волшебного рецепта нет. Чтобы найти ответ для вашего случая, мне нужны все файлы вашего проекта и как минимум минут 15 с ними поработать.